# In a totally ordered topological space that is connected and metrizable, does every sequence have a monotone subsequence?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, metrizability

I am wondering if in a totally ordered topological space (order topology) that is connected (hence linear continuum) and metrizable, does every sequence have a monotone subsequence?

Can we generalize this theorem for every totally ordered topological space?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has nothing to do with topology, the question is simply whether every sequence $\Bbb N\to P$, where $P$ is a totally ordered set, has a monotone subsequence, and the usual proof done for sequences $\Bbb N\to\Bbb R$ works without changes.

Namely let $(p_i)_{i\in\Bbb N}$ be a sequence in $P$. We say that $p_k$ is a peak of the sequence if $l>k$ implies $p_k\geq p_l$. We now distinguish different cases:

If there are infinitely many peaks then the subsequence of peaks is an infinite nonincreasing sequence.

If there are finitely many peaks let $i_1$ be such that $p_{i_1}$ is the successor of the last peak. Since $p_{i_1}$ is not a peak we can find $i_2>i_1$ such that $p_{i_2}\geq p_{i_1}$. Since $p_{i_2}$ is not a peak we can find $i_3>i_2$ such that $p_{i_1}\leq p_{i_2}\leq p_{i_3}$. Continue this construction inductively to get a nondecreasing subsequence.

Comment: Yes, that's the standard proof. In particular your definition of "peak" is what people usually say. Seems to me it would be much better to say that $k$ is a peak if [etc]. Because with the terminology you're using it can happen that $p_2=p_4$, $p_4$ is a peak but $p_2$ is not. This offends my sense of propriety:  If $p_2=p_4$ then anything you can say about $p_4$ is also true of $p_2$. (It shows that peakness is really a property of $k$, _not_ a property of  $p_k$.)

Comment: For me the standard proof is Ramsey's theorem $(\omega)^2_2 \to \omega$.

Comment: Fair enough, that's a nice way to look at it, not one that would be very popular among students at the point in their mathematical career where they first learn that every sequence has a monotone sequence I'm afraid though! (Also did you write the arrow backward or are partition relations written both ways with the same meaning? I've never seen it before) @HennoBrandsma

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti i learnt Ramsey first. And the arrow should be from $\omega$ maybe.